# Good book on English for academic writing and speaking for non-native speakers

Tags: writing, books

I'm not native speaker so I always have some problems with academic writing and speaking. Any good book for English in the academic context generally or for Computer Science in particular (writing or speaking)?

Answer (score 11):

English is not my first language either, but have taught myself through "academic-immersion".  Here are a couple of recommendations that may be of help:

["Computer Science Writing"](http://dblab.cs.toronto.edu/~miller/Research/writing.html) - this is a website with an outline of good practice and links to various other sources.

["Writing for Computer Science"](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=J3hCp9G7mSIC&dq=english%20writing%20skills%20for%20computer%20science&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w54_UtT8GYb8iQLCpoGIAw&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAA) (Zobel, 2004) - this book has a couple of high reviews.

Answer (score 10):

For English for non-native speakers I strongly recommend:

> Day, R.A. & Sakaduski, N.., 2011. Scientific English. A guide for scientists and other professionals. Third edition. Greenwood, Santa Barbara CA.
>
> Glasman-Deal, H., 2012. Science research writing for non-native speakers of English. Imperial College Press, London.

Both cover general writing in English. In addition, it is difficult to avoid

> Strunk, W. Jr & White E.B., The elements of style. Fourth Edition. Longman, New York.

The latter is a classic usually referred to as just Strunk & White.

Comment: +1 for the classic Strunk and White. Superb book for concise, easy to understand writing.

Answer (score 9):

It would be useful if you wrote your research area. For a mathematician, Nicholas Higham's "[Handbook of Writing for the Mathematical Sciences](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/hwms/)" is a good choice.

Comment: Computer Science

Comment: Add it to your question, as not everyone will be interested in comments under one of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend

- English for Writing Research Papers
- English for Presentations at International Conferences
- English for Academic Correspondence and Socializing

all written by Adrian Wallwork and published by Springer.

The author shows examples from his work as a reviewer and a language teacher/professor and corrects them, so he writes an original version and the revised version. In some cases he mentiones specific problems of people from several countries with the English language.
The author wrote also a grammar book, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the following books:

- On Writing Well : William Zinsser;
- The Elements of Style : Strunk and White;
- Sin and Syntax : Constance Hale;

Source: SciWrite: Writing in the Sciences.

You may also take the online course i.e. *Writing in the Sciences* at the following website:

https://class.stanford.edu/courses/Medicine/SciWrite/Fall2013/about

Answer (score 0):

Loved Alley's book because it focuses on scientific/technical writing as a craft and highlights quality criteria of scientific writing:

> Alley, M. (1996). *The Craft of Scientific Writing* (3rd ed.). New York: Springer.