# There are any website to review my non native english?

Tags: writing, peer-review

as you can guess I'm a non-native english.
When I write an scientific paper, my major trouble is the language and I'm worried about the review of my english.
There are any website or community, where I can post my full paper or part of it, and receive a peer review for my english?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: See also http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12904/good-book-on-english-for-academic-writing-and-speaking-for-non-native-speakers?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You're asking people to do difficult, specialized work for free. So, generally... no.

Your university may have a graduate writing center where they can help you.

You could ask a peer in your program to help you, in exchange for cooking lessons, baby sitting, or help with their *_*.

You could hire a professional editor. These can be cheaper than you expect, given the economy, but you also get what you pay for.